# Lyx citation style: et al only when three or more authors

Tags: lyx, citing

I'm using lyx and bibtex for my master thesis. In lyx, I changed the bibliography style from standard to natbib (author-year). The problem occurs when I cite a paper with two authors. The reference to the paper is then like "Kahneman et al. (1979)" instead of "Kahnemann & Tversky (1979)". According to Harvard citation style, "et.al." should be used when three or more authors, not for two. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: If you click on your bibliography inset (the grey box that says "BibTeX Generated Bibliography", what do you have under "Style"? Do you get your desired PDF output after you change the style to "kluwer"?

Comment: for the bibliography I have a custom style (economet). The problem occurs not in the bibliography but when i cite a paper within the text.

Comment: I believe the bibliography style determines that. Can you try changing to kluwer and see what happens in the PDF output to the citations in the text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: @scottkosty indeed it determines the citations in the text. thank you. Now there it only a small matter left: how can I change the "and" between the two name to a "&"?

Comment: @Clemens I think you have to choose a bibliography style that does that. Or create your own (not quite as hard as it sounds).

Answer (score 1):

A well-known bibliography style that generates authoryear-style citation call-outs *and* uses `&` as the conjunction if the bib entry has exactly two authors (or editors) is `agsm`. This bibliography style is part of the `harvard` citation management package, but it's compatible with the `natbib` package as well.